# How to show hidden characters

Tags: mysql

I need to check whether for specific table and specific row for all columns if within any of them there are some hidden characters besides what is already visible.

something like (pseudo code):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE inAnyofColumns there are hidden characters Then Show that columns and that characters.
```

Comment: What do you want to define as a "hidden" character? Are you thinking of things like ASCII control codes?

Comment: the problem is i have problems loading to database and i suspect something within columns containing characters that could raise such problems i just would like to take example row and check content of columns besides what i see if there something within which i do not see

Comment: The problem is, you need to be able to describe to the computer what you're looking for, and neither "things I can't see" or "things that might cause problems" are tight enough descriptions. Maybe you need to re-focus the question around the error you're seeing, and ask for help identifying the cause?

Comment: You can use regex to find non-standard characters. something like this:  `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnToCheck NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';`. you need to define your own regex by considering your needs.

Comment: @MojtabaSayari Can i somehow check for all columns at once?

Comment: @Henry unfortunately we don't have any shortcut for that in SQL. you can do something like this `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE col1 NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]' OR col2 NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9] .... '`. for each table